# Manipulating Android WebView with anchors in HTML

Tags: android, html, webview, scroll, anchor

I use Web View for navigating HTML with anchors to jump to chapters by links from the Content section. Trying to save scroll position and restore it next session with `mWebView.scrollTo(0, positionY)`, get a trouble with jumping to selected anchor: WebView shows not anchor point, but adds `positionY` to the point. I am searching for a method to make `positionY = 0` in it when the user clicks on the content item, but no result yet.

Could you give me a tip on the method or even tell me a better way to solve the problem, please?

PS: If you need to look how the app does work here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.yurinevenchenov1970.easter) (the link is not for promotion, because the book is in Russian, and you will delete the app immediately after having a look, decreasing the rating; it's Just for explaining details of the question).